# VBA code to combine powerquery tables into one new table

Tags: vba, powerquery

Ok, here's my issue, I managed to dynamicly load new tables into the powerquery datamodel.
I would like to combine all these tables into one new one called Allcontrols.
My approach is to try a for each loop and add every new table seperatly.
So far I am getting an error in m om the code in the combine tables section. Help is much appreciated.

```
Sub Add_Connection_All_Tables()
    'Creates Connection Only Queries to all tables in the active workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim wq As WorkbookQuery
    Dim bExists As Boolean
    Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim vbDataModel As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dStart As Double
    Dim dTime As Double
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    
    Unprotectwb
    UnprotectSh
    
        'Set variables
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Clear connections
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Delete
        Next
        
        'Clear queries
        For Each wq In wb.Queries
        wq.Delete
        Next wq
        
        
        'Loop sheets and tables
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
            
            sName = lo.Name
          If Left(sName, 3) Like "WP_" Then
            sFormula = "Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""" & sName & """]}[Content]"
           
            
            'Check if query exists
            bExists = False
            For Each wq In wb.Queries
              If InStr(1, wq.Formula, sFormula) > 0 Then
                bExists = True
              End If
            Next wq
            
            'Add query if it does not exist
            If bExists = False Then
            
              'Add query
              wb.Queries.Add Name:=sName, _
                             Formula:="let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""" & sName & """]}[Content]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
              'Add connection
              wb.Connections.Add2 Name:="Query - " & sName, _
                                  Description:="Connection to the '" & sName & "' query in the workbook.", _
                                  ConnectionString:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & sName & ";Extended Properties=""""", _
                                  CommandText:="SELECT * FROM [" & sName & "]", _
                                  lCmdtype:=2, _
                                  CreateModelConnection:=False, _
                                  ImportRelationships:=False
                                  
               'Add to datamodel
              wb.Connections.Add2 Name:="Query - " & sName, _
                                    Description:="Connection to the '" & sName & "' query in the workbook.", _
                                    ConnectionString:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & sName & ";Extended Properties=", _
                                    CommandText:="" & sName & "", _
                                    lCmdtype:=6, _
                                    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
                                    ImportRelationships:=False
```

'Combine tables section

```
            ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Allcontrols", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Table.Combine({""" & sName & """})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
       
             End If
            
            End If
            
            
          Next lo
        Next ws
    
      
    
    'Protectwb
    'ProtectSh
    End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like an extraordinarily painful way of doing things. Why not define the PQ in another workbook, so it can simply query the tables of the original workbook directly, without any VBA?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, it is composed as an audit file, every information needs to go into one file unfortunatly